# Trouble linking to correct libxml2 when installing libxslt

Tags: unix, libxml2, configure, osx-leopard, libxslt

Trying to install `libxslt-1.1.24` but getting an error during `./configure` that says:

```
checking for libxml libraries >= 2.6.27... configure: error: Version 2.6.16 found. You need at least libxml2 2.6.27 for this version of libxslt
```

but `libxml2-2.7.3` was JUST installed and can be seen in `/usr/local/include/libxml2`

How do I get `libxslt` to link to new `libxml2` when `./configure`?

Answer (score 4):

The various `--with-libxml-*` arguments will allow you to point it to your alternate install of libxml2. See `./configure --help` for more details.

Comment: I have the same issue but I specified those: `./autogen.sh --prefix=/opt/libxslt --with-libxml-prefix=/opt/libxml2 --with-libxml-include-dir=/opt/libxml2/include --with-libxml-libs-prefix=/opt/libxml2/lib --with-libxml-src=/usr/src/libxml2`. Still the same as above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if your ld cache would have been rebuilt by the libxslt install, but if not, try refreshing it by running:

```
ldconfig
```

(make sure /usr/local/lib is already in /etc/ld.so/conf).
Again, you may be linking static, or the cache may already be up-to-date, so this may not matter... but worth a shot I suppose.

Comment: The loader configuration does not tell the linker where to find libraries.